# how to express @ sign in URl

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I was doing self.request.path and got the the path which is the email address, for example, example@hotmail.com,  the it cant display it the way it was, it shows like example01_hotmail.com, all cgi.urlencode(), is there a way that the self.request.path could return the integral url? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLEncode the "@" as %40. URL should look like:

http://example.com/blah?email=example%40hotmail.com